# Prevent Any Subclass for Overriding/Hiding Method c#; Preserve method Signature for superclass

Tags: c#, oop

My Question belongs to this scenario

```
class A
{
    public virtual void show()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from A;");
    }
}
class B:A
{
    public sealed override void show()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from B;");
    }
}
class C:B
{
    public new void show()
    {          
         Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from C;");         
    }          
}
```

## OR

```
class A
 {
      public  void show()
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from A;");
      }
 }
 class B:A
 {
      public new void show()
      {
               Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from B;");
      }
 }
```

In above code Class C hides Class B's Method Show()

> Q. How i can be sure that **no Subclass Override** as well as **Hides** method
>   which are **already defined in SuperClass**

something like this or May be something like `readonly` Keyword which is used for Fields

```
 class A1
 {
      public sealed void show() // I know it will give compilation error
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Hey! This is from A1");
      }
 }
 class B1 : A1
 {
      public void show()
      {
           Console.WriteLine("You must get a compilation Error if you create method with this name and parameter");
      }
 }
```

#### Is there any such key word?

**Edit 1:**

> Yes i want to prevent the extender to be sure that it uses the right
>   implementation with the method name and parameter coz if some one else
>   looks into code it should be right

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, there is no way to enforce that with the compiler.

Comment: Why would you be so distrusting of your extenders? If you don't use the `new` keyword, you get a warning, so it's not likely that you'll do it by accident. In the rare cases I use the `new` keyword, I'm doing it with the understanding that I'm doing a potentially bad thing. If there's a strong reason for people to want to do this, maybe something else about the class structure should be improved, to remove that reason.

Comment: @TimS. Yes i want to prevent the extender to be sure that it uses the right implementation with the method name and parameter coz if some one else looks into code it should be right

Comment: Mentioning Java isn't really relevant.  Java **doesn't have method hiding in the first place**.  It only has method overriding.  Method overriding can be prevented in both languages.

Comment: @Servy preventing method overriding is the main objective of mine strictly prohibit for the use of same signature

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid That comment doesn't make any sense.  If you only want to prohibit method overriding, you can do that.  Just don't make it virtual or, if it must be virtual because it itself is overriding something, mark it as `sealed`, as you have shown.  It's preventing method hiding that you can't do.

Comment: @Servy I think we are getting confused between overriding/Hiding Neither preventing for overriding nor hiding is my objective 
My main objective is to reserve the method signature if you are extending the class

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid How many times can we say it "**C# does not provide you a way to prevent method hiding other than preventing derived classes totally**". You can prevent ***overriding***, as you showed in `class B:A` in your first example, but **you can not prevent hiding**.

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid And by definition the only way for a subclass to have a method of the exact same signature as a base class is to either override or hide a method.  To prevent that case you need to prevent both overriding and hiding.  If you're okay with preventing overriding but allowing hiding then you can do that.  If you need to prevent hiding you'll need to live with the fact that you just can't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way you can prevent there being a subclass that hides the method is to make the class `sealed`, thus preventing any subclasses.  If there can be any subclasses then they can shadow the method and there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are depending on `A` and `B` not having their methods overridden, `sealed` does the job. If you wish to prevent method hiding, ensure all members requiring `A`, or an inheritor, are defined as `A` or `B`.

Consider the following:

```
A a = new A();
a.show(); // "Hey! This is from A;"

A a = new B();
a.show(); // "Hey! This is from B;"

B b = new B();
b.show(); // "Hey! This is from B;"

A a = new C();
a.show(); // "Hey! This is from B;"

B b = new C();
b.show(); // "Hey! This is from B;"
```

Only when you refer to `C` as `C` does the `new` keyword kick in.

```
C c = new C();
c.show(); // "Hey! This is from C;"
```

In summary, your implementation should use only define instances of `A` and `B` as `A` or `B`. In fact, unless something like `C` is implemented in your assembly, your code can not be forced to call `C`'s `public new void show()`.